# sometimes Wireshark does not capture ongoing tcp traffic

Tags: sockets, wireshark, winsock

I have a TCP socket client and a server on different hosts within local networks. They engage in a simple P2P request and response data exchange.

Occasionally, I encounter sudden disconnections and have attempted to troubleshoot the issue using Wireshark.

Typically, the client and server operate smoothly, and Wireshark captures the data traffic adequately.

However, on certain occasions, Wireshark only captures the initial portion of the data traffic, failing to display any further data (except for TCP keep-alive traffic), despite the ongoing data exchange at the application level between the client and server.

What could be the cause of this peculiar behavior? Notably, each time this occurs, the socket connection eventually breaks (typically after an additional two minutes in my case). Consequently, the client, implemented with Winsok, reports a socket error 10054.

Comment: What you describe as no data except keep-alive an connection breaking after additional two minutes actually sounds like that no data are actually transferred and that due to keep-alive a connection loss was detected or idle timeout happened. I would therefore more question your statement of "despite the ongoing data exchange at the application level between the client and server.", i.e. is there really a data transfer going on (instead of just processing already read data) and it is what you are looking at with Wireshark (i.e. TCP not UDP, the specific interface you capture on ...)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes, it is exactly the strange part. The data transfer is seen and verified at application level. The Wireshark just did not show any data from some point. It should not be due to timing or filter in Wireshark, because I repeat the test several times in the same way and most of them behaves just normal.